# Сравнить список и ключи словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список - `['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5']`

Есть словарь -

```
{
 'name1':{'1':'2'},
 'name2':{'1':'2'},
 'name3':{'1':'2'},
 'name4':{'1':'2'},
 'name5':{'1':'2'},
 'name6':{'1':'2'}
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы в третью переменную записывался элемент словаря `{'name6':{'1':'2'}...}`, в том случае, если ключа словаря нет в списке. Ни список, ни словарь не отсортирован, поэтому проходится надо каждый ключ словарь по всем элементам списка.

Пробовала перебирать список и словарь вложенными циклами, но он выдает ошибку

> TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable,

поэтому ищу возможность. Нужен словарь такого вида, так как потом он записывается в json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, как вы пробовали - код в вопросе вы не привели. обычным перебором ключей по списку вполне себе решается задача:

```
l = ['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5']
d = {'name1':{'1':'2'},'name2':{'1':'2'},'name3':{'1':'2'},'name4':{'1':'2'},'name5':{'1':'2'},'name6':{'1':'2'}}
s = set(l) # если у вас в списке могут быть неуникальные значения
           # иначе просто опустите эту строку и в строке ниже
           # измените s на имя вашего списка.
res = {k:d[k] for k in d.keys() if k not in s}
```

res:

```
{'name6': {'1': '2'}}
```